# How To Remove click effect from a QPushButton

Tags: css, qt, styles, stylesheet, appearance

In QT: I only want to show an icon and some text, so I use QPushButton. But how can I remove the click effect from it?

Comment: What do you mean 'click' effect?  Do you mean the 3D bevel?

Comment: I think he wants to use QPushButton basically as a QLabel with Text and Icon displayed at the same time ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass QPushButton and ignore all events but the Paint event:

```
class IconLabel : public QPushButton {

...

bool IconLabel::event ( QEvent * e ) {
   if (e->type() == QEvent::Paint) {
      return QPushButton::event(e);
   }
   return true;
}
```

Depending on your requirements, it might be necessary to let additional events pass through, like if you want to use a tooltip on your IconLabel:

```
   if (e->type() == QEvent::Paint ||
       e->type() == QEvent::ToolTip) {
      return QPushButton::event(e);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this [solution](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/3256-Qlabel-with-%28icon-and-text%29-HowTo) but looks like it should work.

Copying from the link above

Use rich text for the label, e.g:

```
lbl->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
lbl->setText("<img src=":/myimage.png">Hello!");
```

Comment: Nice solution :-) Just tried it and it works well (slightly modified the setText() call: `lbl->setText("<img src=\"myimage.png\">Hello!");`, it also depends on whether you are using a resource or a local file). The style is a bit different from the QPushButton approach, e.g. no frame, but this depends on the OPs specific requirements and can surely be adjusted by some stylesheet.